# Setting FLASK_APP in an (semi)automated way

Tags: bash, shell, flask, environment-variables

Before I run my Flask application using

```
$ flask run
```

I need to set few environment variables (e.g. FLASK_APP pointing to the application file). I've been trying to automate the process with a .sh script:

```
export FLASK_APP=application.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
echo $FLASK_APP
echo $FLASK_DEBUG
```

It turns out that even if the last two lines print out the input from the first two lines, Flask doesn't seem to care. If I want to set the variables so that Flask changes its behaviour, I must do it manually by typing the first two lines from the script in the terminal:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=application.py
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

What am I doing wrong when it comes to the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running your shell script as:

```
$ path_to_your_script.sh
```

This loads another shell and executes a script.

---

If you want to set environment variables for you current shell, use:

```
$ source path_to_your_script.sh
```

or (*dot at the beginning*)

```
$ . path_to_your_script.sh
```